# iOS 9 autolayout and layoutsubviews different from iOS 8<

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, layoutsubviews

iOS 9 doesn't load autolayout in layoutSubviews() as it should..

I'm tying to add shadow under a view(container) in my custom uitableviewcell, which it works good on iOS 8, but not iOS 9. But it is working when I scroll the tableview and start reusing cell.

```
//DidMoveToSuperview is required
- (void)didMoveToSuperview{
  [super didMoveToSuperview];

  [self setNeedsLayout];
  [self layoutIfNeeded];
}  

- (void)layoutSubviews {
  [super layoutSubviews];

  NSLog(@"container bound: %@", @(self.containerView.bounds.size.width));
  NSLog(@"cell width: %@", @(self.frame.size.width));

  UIBezierPath *shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.containerView.bounds];
  self.containerView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
  self.containerView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
  self.containerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 5.0f);
  self.containerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5f;
  self.containerView.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath;
}
```

1st Log : container bound width on iOS 8 is OK, iOS 9 is not ok

2nd Log : cell width is Ok on iOS 8 and 9

Any clue ?

Comment: Any new about that? I'm stuck with similar issue.